# Finding all location tags within a country

Tags: discussion, tagging

I want to be able to find all tags (such as [tokyo-haneda](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tokyo-haneda)) that are within a country (such as [japan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japan)), so that I can favorite them and therefore their questions appear in a yellow background when browsing the front page.

Is there any way of doing so?

Comment: So THAT is the reason for the yellow background!

Comment: This could be done if we changed our tags to always be **country-state/province/area-city** by favoriting **japan-*** :) (not that I'm really suggesting we do this)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there is no direct way, I just wrote a small SQL Query to [search the tags for a word](http://data.stackexchange.com/travel/query/edit/203364/find-tags-by-keyword), it works ok for tags with that keyword, the problem is, many of these tags do not have wikis so you can not find them in search, perhaps you can write a wiki for few of them.

Comment: Can you make a SQL query which can help me find all the tags without tag wikis? I'll be more than happy doing this.

Comment: @AdityaSomani here it is: http://data.stackexchange.com/travel/query/203481